# Reverse and merge a linked list

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, linked-list

Problem: Given a sorted linked list

```
1->2->3->4->5->6->7
```

change the pointers in the linked list to make it

```
7->1->6->2->5->3->4
```

using constant space.

I tried to solve it using the following algorithm:

1. Find the middle node of the linked list using 2 nodes, a fast node and a slow node.
2. Reverse the linked list from the middle node. Mark the middle node as y and start node as x.

   ```
   1->2->3->7->6->5->4
   x        y
   ```
3. If y=middle node AND y!= x.next, then swap y and x.next. Then swap x and x.next.

   ```
   1->7->3->2->6->5->4
   x        y
   7->1->3->2->6->5->4
   x        y
   ```

   Advance x by two nodes and y by 1 node.

   ```
   7->1->3->2->6->5->4
         x     y
   ```
4. Now if (x != y) { swap x and y }

   ```
   7->1->6->2->3->5->4
         x     y
   ```
5. Advance x by two nodes and y by 1 node

   ```
   7->1->3->2->6->5->4
               x  y
   ```
6. Repeat steps 4 and 5 till y becomes null (reaches end of linked list) or x == y

So finally we get

```
7->1->6->2->5->3->4
```

**Question:**

Is there a simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simple solution:

1. Found list size.
2. Spilt by 2 same lists.
3. Reverse second part.
4. Merge lists.

Sample:

1. `1->2->3->4->5->6->7`  size is `7`. (We should split by 4 and 3)
2. Split by `1->2->3->4` and `5->6->7`
3. Reverse second part `1->2->3->4` and `7->6->5`
4. Merge: `7->1->6->2->5->3->4`

Comment: 1 from second list, 1 from first list, 1 from second list and etc.

Comment: The demand was to use constant space; merging the two lists separately would need a separate output list. I'm trying to change the pointers in the original list so as to get the output..

Comment: Merging not require extra space, just modify links into nodes.

Answer (score 0):

You can find two sophisticated solutions in [Linked list problem](http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/105/LinkedListProblems.pdf) problem  17 and 18.

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I do know how to reverse a linked list. I was asking specifically about this problem.